# What is the smallest four-digit number $\overline{999a}$ which can be presented as the sum of two cubes?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> What is the smallest four-digit number of the kind $\overline{999a}$ which can be presented as the sum of
>   the cubes of two different natural numbers? ($a$ is a digit)?

$x^3 + y^3 = 999a$

No calculators are allowed in this apparently.

I don't see an obvious method here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is $9990=21^3+9^3$.

---

The biggest cube less than $10000$ is $21^3$ or $9261$

So, I tried to find $x$ such that
$$9990-9261\le x^3\lt 10000-9261.$$
Then, I found $9990-21^3=9990-9261=729=9^3$.